# Can't reset pgAdmin4-web main account

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have a debian 12 server with postgres running. I already setup pgadmin web some time ago and completely forgot the username and password i specified at installation. Because of that i uninstalled pgadmin and deleted all the config files i could find(/usr/pgadmin4). After reinstalling, i ran the setup script, but i was not asked to set up username or password, neither was i asked when first connecting to the website, i only saw the login site.

I reinstalled postgres and deleted its config, but that didn't help either and i was not able to find any more config files.
I'm on pgadmin 8.3 and postgres 16.2.

Comment: 1) Reinstalling Postgres has nothing to do with pgAdmin4. pgAdmin4 is just a GUI client. 2) Just use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and get more done.